# Loop invariation about inner loop of insert sort

Tags: java, sorting

I think for a while and trap into the problem.

When I wanted to specify the loop invariation in the inner loop of insert sort, I couldn't express the meaning with formal technical language clearly.

Please, help me!!!

```java
        /*
         *  Invariation:
         *   
         *    1. outer: all in [left, i] is sorted before each outer loop
         *    2. inner: 
         *           I couldn't organize the formal language very well 
         *
         */

        for(int i = left, j = i; i < right; j = ++i) {
            int ai = arr[i + 1];
            
            // look for the proper position for ai inserted
            while(ai < arr[j]) {
                a[j + 1] = a[j];
                if(j-- == left) break;
            }

            // insert ai to the appropriate position
            a[j + 1] = ai;
        }
```

I expect someone can help me complete the code comment.

Thanks very very much!!!

Comment: Please help by explaining your problem using non-technical language by (for example) providing input data, and expected output data.

Comment: Pleas do not hesitate to add a [tag] about the language you are using. ([tag:c#] ??)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot adding the java tag to the code.

Comment: I still do not see it, so I will add it for you...